# ハッカーは個人宅のIPアドレスを入手した後どのように個別のパソコンに対して侵入を行うのでしょうか？

Tags: security

1.メールの送信元からグローバルIPアドレスを入手
2.この時点で相手のブロードバンド・ルータに当てられているIPアドレスがわかる。

ここまでは想像がつくのですが、その後DHCPサーバ機能でローカルのIPアドレスが割り振られていると思うのですが個別のパソコンに対してどのように攻撃するのでしょうか？
Ping グローバルIP.ローカルIPのようにパケットを投げかけたりできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単にIPアドレスがわかったとしても侵入できるとは限りません。
そのIPのルータのファームウェアや、そのIPのPC上にあるサーバー等の脆弱性を狙ってルート権限の奪取を試みるのです。
おそらくですが、最近はそんな真正面からのアタックは珍しくなってるでしょう。OSやソフトのアップデートを適宜やっていれば致命的なセキュリティホールはすぐ塞がれるので。（まれにゼロデイ攻撃とかはありますが。）
今どきはウィルスやマクロ、ブラウザ等で不特定多数に対しバックドアを仕掛けて足がかりとし、目的企業に対して標的型攻撃を仕掛けるということが多いと思われます。

フィクション的なハッカーの場合は、そのハッカーだけが知っている致命的なセキュリティホールがあり、それがベンダーにも伝わっていないので、好きなタイミングでハッカーが侵入できる。
というような形になるかと思います。

Comment: Ipのpc上のサーバというのはブロードバンドルータの内側ですか？いまいちピンとこなくてすいません。

Comment: WEBサーバーやファイルサーバーを自宅のPC等で建てる場合のことです。
また通信をホストとして受けるアプリケーション(P2Pやクライアント-ホスト型のゲーム等)の可能性もあります。

とにかくソケットを監視し、何らかのポートを介して通信している場合はアタックが試みられるものと思います。

Comment: dropboxなどもホストとしてlistenしてると思うのですが、それを探すということでしょうか？ソケットの監視はブロードバンド・ルータに割り振られたグローバルIPから可能なのでしょうか？そのパケット通信がブロードバンド・ルータに接続されたどの端末から発信されているなどもわかるのでしょうか？

Comment: ソケットの監視というよりは、適当な信号を送り応答のあるポートを特定する形になります。

Comment: どの端末から発信されているかは重要ではありません。脆弱性のあるサービスを行っているサーバーがあれば、そこにハッキングを行い、バックドアを仕掛けられればLAN内の情報を取得することは可能です。

Comment: 詳しくありがとうございます。

Comment: wataru さんは「個人宅のPC」を前提にしている一方、kareidscope 1123 さんは「(脆弱性のある) サーバー」の話をしていて、お互いに齟齬があるように見えます。

Answer (score 0):

例えばメールに添付された実行ファイルを間違って実行したとします。
もしかしたら、その実行ファイルはリモートデスクトップ用のプログラムかもしれません。
また、いったん実行したら、そのプログラムは常駐するように作られているかもしれません。
その場合、ハッカーは何でもできるようになります。